# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when trying to send message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to send a message through discord.js and I am getting the following error:
`(node:10328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
// Init
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const channel = bot.users.cache.get('4257');

// Vars

// Code
bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("The Bot is ready!");

    channel.send("Test");
});


// Login
bot.login(" "); // I will hide this.
```

What is wrong? Is it the id on the channel variable? I just put in the id of my bot since I didn't know what to put in it.
[image]

At first I gave it all the permissions under "Text Permissions", but I also tried giving him admin privs. It still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the issue is in the line `const channel = bot.users.cache.get('4257');`, it seems to be returning undefined.

Comment: Yes, but why? Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: you most likely need to dive into the docs and see if you're using the functions correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The problem is this line:

```js
const channel = bot.users.cache.get('4257');
```

---

#### Here's what's wrong with it:

```js
const channel = bot.users.cache // this returns a collection of users, you want channels.
.get('4257'); // this is a user discriminator, you want a channel ID
```

---

#### Here's how to fix it:

```js
const id = <ID of channel you want to send the message to>
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get(id)

// ...

channel.send('Test')
```

---

#### Here's an example:

```js
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('699220239698886679')
channel.send('This is the #general channel in my personal Discord')
```

---

- [How to get a `Channel ID`](https://kb.statbot.net/faq/how-do-i-find-my-server-user-channel-id/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20a%20Channel%20ID,the%20number%20is%20the%20ID.)
- [`ChannelManager` Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager)

Comment: Also, '4257', which you originally said was the ID of your bot, is actually the discriminator. User IDs look more like this: `713102337908015227`.

To find your bot's ID, you can run `console.log(bot.user.id)`. [Learn all the properties of `user` here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)

Comment: I tried it but it still comes with the same error. Let me try this on a different script and server.

Comment: What did you put in for the Channel ID?

Comment: I passed it in the `bot.channels.cache.get();` function just like you did. Then I called the send function.

Comment: But what channel ID did you use? If you're using the one I provided in my example, it won't work. See https://kb.statbot.net/faq/how-do-i-find-my-server-user-channel-id/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20a%20Channel%20ID,the%20number%20is%20the%20ID. to learn how to find a channel ID

Comment: I used 744612164668620902

Comment: hm, that's very weird. Try `console.log(bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === <name of channel you want to send messages to>))` and see what it returns

Comment: The id that it gave me worked! The id that the other command was giving me turned out to be my **Server** ID, not my channel id. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help 

Answer (score -1):

const channel is empty here. You need to make sure value should be assigned in it.

```
channel.send("Test");
```

If its not mendatory that value will come then use try-catch.

```
try {
 channel.send("Test");
} catch(e) {
 console.log(e)
}
```

Please support with vote or answered if it helps, thanks.

Comment: The try-catch didn't help. I also tried just running the command straight forward: `bot.users.cache.get('4257').send("Test");`

Comment: You don't understand try catch is to solve exception. Your problem is below code is not giving any value. You need solve that. `.send("Test")` is not a problem.
bot.users.cache.get('4257')